# Prevent Timer from Garbage Collection

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I am starting a timer at the beginning of my program with:

```
GetWorldTimerManager().SetTimer(MyTimerHandle, this, &AMyGameMode::SetNextMatchState, 1.0f, true, 0.0f);
```

MyTimerHandle is a private variable within my GameMode.

This calls the corresponding function every second and checks if the game is supposed to get into the next state. It works perfectly fine until I start destroying actors from the scene. From that point, the callback is no longer called. My destroy call looks like this:

```
Destroy(Cast<AMyPlayerState>(gameState->PlayerArray[i])->MyUnitList.Pop());
```

So I am not deleting the timer. And since "Destroy(...)" only marks an actor to be destroyed by the GC in the near future, I assume that the GC also deletes my timer, which is obviously not what I intended to to.

So how can I prevent the GC to destroy my timer (assuming this is the reason, why the timer stops working) ?

Comment: Hi, I don't know what is the issue you are having (you should try to debug the timer manager) but to my knowledge timers are not UObject and as such are not part of the GC. Actors can get GCed, and then their timer(s) stop firing, but your timer is attached to the GameMode that should live forever... Are you somehow trying to change the Game Mode dynamically?

Comment: Hmm, well how can I debug the timer manager? I am not holding a reference to it, only to the handle. If I remove the Destroy(...) line, the timer works as intended. So I am not touching the Game Mode itself. So either by destroying the actor, the timer is being destroyed too (I am not sure why this would happen), or the Destroy method triggers something inside the engine to make the timer stop.

Comment: Well, I am not in front of a computer, but somewhere in the World Timer manager is a list of active timers being evaluated regularly ; you can watch it to see when your timer get removed.

Comment: I fail to find the World Timer manager. Am I supposed to find it within the Unreal Engine or in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

Are you perhaps loading a new map? Load Map, Travel...

Because this would create a new World, with it's own new Timer Manager, which would cause you timer to get disabled.

In this case you should use the Timer Manager from the Game Instance instead of the World

Comment: No, I am not. I just changed my code to use the one of the GameInstance (just in case) and it doesn't change anything. As mentioned above, if I remove the Destroy(..) line, everything works as intended and the timer keeps ticking.